# kendo grid on 'incell editing mode' doesn't accept value changes, while using mobile phone

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid, telerik

the Kendo grid does't accept cell value changes when using an android mobile phone with the Chrome browser.
You can test it on the Telerik demo [https:demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing).

for example, change the value of the Unit Price and go to the other cell. you will see that the value will become the original value.

just by touching somewhere outside the border of the grid the value will change.

Comment: Sounds like something you should report to Telerik directly.

Comment: Do you have .Mobile() enabled on the grid?

Comment: Report it here: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues . It could be related to [this bug](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/4432)

Comment: Kevin - Yes i have .Mobile() enabled on the grid
GaloisGirl - It's not related to that bug unfortunately
CarstenFranke - I have reported to Telerik but no response...

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has answered this and it works fine.

Hello Amin,

Thank you for reporting this. This is a bug, and thus, I converted this ticket into a public bug report:
    https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-jquery-ui/1421654-kendo-grid-on-incell-editing-mode-doesn-t-accept-value-changes-while-using-mobile-phone

As a workaround, handle cellClose event and trigger the blur event of the child input.

```
function onCellClose(e) {
    e.container.find("input").trigger("blur");
}
```